# Нужно ли выносить не очень важные данные в отдельную таблицу MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Имеем такую ситуацию, есть основная сущность со своими основными данными и есть еще дополнительные данные о ней которые нужно хранить, но отображаться будут они при определенной логике не очень часто. В поиске не участвуют, просто текст который надо показать в определенный момент.

Стоит ли такого плана данные помещать в основую таблицу сущности, или может быть стоить создать таблицу типа `entity_metadata` и там поля `entity_id`, `name` и `value` где и будут лежать эти не оч важные данные основной сущности в `ключ-значение` ?

Но тут сразу возникает вопрос, если будет по 5 записей метаданных к каждой основной в итоге получим таблицу в который будет в 5 раз больше записей, не скажется ли это на производительности mysql сервера? Какой вариант лучше и правильнее?

Comment: Собрать 5 записей при показе одной сущности конечно медленнее, чем если бы они все лежали в записи. Но с другой стороны, если они не нужны, но занимают место в основной записи, то и например отображение списка объектов будет дольше, ибо с диска надо больше поднимать из за большой длины записи. И еще вопрос - потребуется ли поиск по value второй таблицы, если да, то тогда эта вторая таблица единственно верный формат хранения, потому что там поле можно проиндексировать. А если они окажутся в основной таблице, то либо много индексов (а одновременно работает только 1) либо вообще перебор таблицы

Comment: Вот и у меня такое же "бить или"... Поиска по value не будет, будет на данный момент просто до 5 доп записей к одной основной записи. То есть если будет 1 000 000 основных записей то в entity_metada будет 5 000 000 записей, меня это и стремает. Ну миллион ерудна, а если будет 100 миллионов... Что если эти не оч важные данные хранить в виде json в основной таблице?

Comment: Все таки вопрос, как часто будут использоваться данные и в каком виде. Если не будет запросов вроде "дай мне несколько сотен объектов и по ним по всем дай еще и эти доп поля" - то спокойно выносите и не парьтесь. Много записей не проблема когда по индексу добираетесь. Вы длину еще этих данных прикиньте, если они в json то это увеличивает запись основной таблицы, значит на страницу умещается меньше записей, а значит даже элементарный запрос `select count(*)` по таблице будет работать гораздо дольше. Ибо 1 лишний байт длины записи - это уже минимум на 1 Мб больше с диска поднимать при 100млн

Answer (score 1):

Наверное стоит следовать нормальным формам таблиц :-)
С точки зрения НФ - именно так и следует сделать, с точки зрения производительности - Вы же сами написали, что данные будут отображаться не так уж часто.

Comment: Я то в основном все так и спроектировал, просто в процессе разработки появились "новые данные" и пока не определюсь где лучше их хранить.

Answer (score 1):

Имеет смысл создать таблицу ключ-значение, как вы описали, только если ключ может быть динамическим или есть разные "типы" с отдельными набором свойств (хотя и тут можно иначе обыграть), или если есть 100% уверенность, что поиска по ним не будет и их ну очень уж много.

Для 5-ти свойств создавать отдельную таблицу, скорее всего смысла не имеет.

Я бы сделал так:

- меньше 20 свойств- в одну таблицу.
- 20-40 полей - две таблицы со связью "один к одному".
- больше 40 - думать, возможно что-то не так с изначальным дизайном. Возможен вариант "ключ-значение".

Вот кстати инфа по влиянию количества колонок (и их типа) на скорость, разница между 1 колонкой и 100 ~ 70%.
https://www.percona.com/blog/2009/09/28/how-number-of-columns-affects-performance/

Comment: В основной таблице 28 колонок. На данный момент будет 5 ключей но возможно будет больше, правки такая штука) Тогда выходит лучше для 5 ключей просто создать колонки в доп таблице, а если появятся новые данные то просто расширить таблицу.

Comment: Ну да по-моему это норм выход, так то будет 1:1 по записям в главной и таблице с метаинфой

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от ситуации, исходя из своего опыта говорю,что не встречал не одной промышленной базы данных построенной по третьей нормальной форме. Задачу оптимизации нужно решать по мере поступления задач, потому что это очень дорого и оптимальное решение как правило плохо расширяется. В данной ситуации вам не стоит беспокоится на этапе проектирования, потому что разделить таблицу всегда можно. У меня встречались таблицы 600+ колонок в которой активно использовались только 20 полей и для этого они дублировались в другой таблице, да избыточность есть но сейчас вопрос с памятью не на столько острая как 10 лет назад.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Ну у нас уже не совсем эта проектирования, просто в процессе разработки зашли правки и добавились данные, которые как по мнению клиента могут понадобиться. 600+ колонок даже не представлял, что такое возможно :)

Comment: Есть системы когда импортируешь всё вне зависимости пригодятся все данные или нет. Требывания программист не ставит вот и получается что существует очень большие данные но не все они активно разом используются